# URI for specifying the context of HTTP requests

Tags: uri, semantic-web

If I request an URL like https://www.w3.org/ns/rdfa in the browser, it automatically loads the HTML version of that resource since the browser also sends `Accept: text/html`. If I request a different media type, such as via `curl -H "Accept: text/turtle" https://www.w3.org/ns/rdfa`, I get a different representation of the resource.

This shows that a single HTTP-based resource may in fact refer to/consist of multiple sub-resources. Preferably, these should all be "views" of the same resource, but they may not be ‒ the content that is loaded could differ by the specified media type, language, the current time, or any other header. While you can store the whole request in a format like WARC that replicates everything about it, you don't usually need to know *every* header sent to the server; only those that produce a different response.

Is there a URI scheme, notation, or another public or proposed standard that makes it possible to refer to these narrower "resources"? It could allow something like this:

```
https://www.w3.org(Accept:text/html)/ns/rdfa
https://www.w3.org(Accept:application/rdf+xml)/ns/rdfa
https://www.w3.org(Accept:text/turtle)/ns/rdfa
```

to identify the three versions of the page with a header that differentiates them, both for the purpose of expressing such a distinction, and for automatically setting the header when such a URL is navigated to. I chose to state the header before the URL path, because the request only contains everything from the first `/` after the hostname (up to `#`), and it makes sense to store it in a place that already affects the headers (hostname sets `Host`, credentials set `Authorization`).

Something that can express this specific distinction are web links, for example the `<link>` tag in HTML:

```html
<link href="https://www.w3.org/ns/rdfa" type="text/html">
<link href="https://www.w3.org/ns/rdfa" type="application/rdf+xml">
<link href="https://www.w3.org/ns/rdfa" type="text/turtle">
```

But that only encodes the media type, and, of course, is not a single URI.

Comment: I'm probably being dense here - but this *isn't* about dereferencable HTTP URIs with content negotiation? https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-vocab-pub/#negotiation

Comment: @Thomas Yes, content negotiation is the primary focus of this question ‒ servers may use it to provide a different version of the resource, and my goal is to *identify* such a version among the others distinguished by the value of `Accept` only. However there are other headers that would be nice to represent too.

Comment: I think content negotiation is primarily about providing a different *represenation* of the same resource rather than different versions of the resource. It would be confusing to request the same version of an ontology, in both json-ld and rdf/xml (let's say in 2 requests), and get two documents that differ in information rather than presentation.
The W3C only mentions content negotiation and only suggests doing it by the accept header. You can write a server to parse *any* header (your own madeup one or not) and you can do anything you want with it, you can even use nonstandard mimetypes.

Comment: @Thomas You are right that "representation" is a better word to use in the context of content negotiation (I did not mean "version" in the software sense). In any case, the server is free to provide anything, so it makes sense to me to be able to identify and distinguish these representation. After all one is an HTML document and the other is an XML document, so it follows to use distinct nodes for the description (for example linked by `dcterms:hasFormat`).

Comment: Then there are other headers that could change what the server responds with, for example `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests`, and generally anything that the server returns in `Vary`. Perhaps something like `If-Unmodified-Since` could be used too to simulate the date information.